# Android source code version mistmatch while debugging on device

Tags: android, android-source

I am facing a mismatch in my android framework source code while debugging it.

I have a Jelly Bean (4.2.2) device. Now i build my android application using API Level 17.
Have also attached the source code downloaded from SDK manager for API level 17.

Now i am trying to debug a web view with embedded video for MediaPlayer.setDataSource.
Whenever it hits the breakpoint in runtime the line number mismatch happens.

I have the latest source code from SDK manager also my device is updated to latest Jelly Bean ( i don't have updates for JB in my device so i expect it is running on the latest code for JB).

I tried by using the source code of JB with both the branches (jb-release and 4.2.2_r1.2) as source code for debugging but again of now help

Any idea why this mismatch will happen ?

cheers,
Saurav

Comment: most likely your device is not a Nexus or the official emulator. The source code only matches perfectly on those cases. Android is open source and manufacturers are free to change stuff as they see fit (as long as it passes Googles compatibility test)

Comment: Yes i am on Samsung Tab 3 and yes probably due to fragmentation i am not able to match the code.

Comment: Fragmentation is something else. That's just open source. If you really have to debug that specific line of on the source code my suggestion is that you do it using either the official Google emulator or maybe even Genymotion (because they don't see to change much).

Comment: @Budius thanks for your inputs and suggestions. I am trying with emulator now.